# How to resolve stack overflow problem during dotnet test?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit, dotnet-test

First my setup:

- .Net Core 3.1 (migrated from 2.2)
- xUnit 2.4.1
- xUnit Runner 2.4.1
- Visual Studio 2019 16.4.2
- Test.SDK 16.4.0

I've just migrated from .Net Core 2.2 to 3.1. I just fixed errors and changed my serializer to System.Text. My app is working just fine but...

> Note: All my tests are integration tests which are using `WebApplicationFactory`.

I was always using Visual Studio Test Runner to run all tests, but then when I tried to Run All I got an error:

> Notice that strange `netcoreapp2.2`, while I'm specifically using .Net Core 3.1 in MyTests and MyApp project.

```
[10.01.2020 2:05:03.939 PM] System.InvalidOperationException: The following TestContainer was not found 'D:\Projects\MyApp\MyTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\GrabGoApiTests.dll'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.TestContainer.TestContainerProvider.<GetTestContainerAsync>d__46.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerConfigurationQueryByTestsBase.<QueryTestContainerConfigurationsAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerConfigurationQuery.<GetTestContainerConfigurationsAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestRunConfiguration.<UpdateAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RunOperation.<RunTestsAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<<Execute>b__37_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility.ILoggerExtensions.<CallWithCatchAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

And then I was thinking "Okay... Maybe VS is acting strange again I'll try running tests from console"

```
PS D:\Projekty\GrabGoAPI> dotnet test
Test run for D:\Projects\MyApp\MyTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\GrabGoApiTests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.3.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...

A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed : Stack overflow.


Test Run Aborted.
Total tests: Unknown
     Passed: 101
 Total time: 26,3009 Seconds
```

And now I'm here.

I found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392039/stackoverflow-in-net-unit-testing-when-references-are-circular). But I cannot Debug tests in Visual Studio to find out which tests are causing the problem.

Also `dotnet test --blame` are blaming random tests every time.

How can I find what is causing that StackOverflow exception?

Comment: Test usually are not executed in an specific order, and an stackoverflow exception is usually generated when the call stack has reached its limit. Both things combined could explain the problem. IMHO a couple of possible causes here: a) recursion and b) huge amount of tests. Hard to tell with the info provided.

Comment: Tests were working with .Net Core 2.2. There are only 267 tests. So it's not a lot. Maybe the problem is somewhere within the System.Text JsonSerializer... I don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was due to System.Text.Json not handling `Reference Loop` as `JSON.Net` did.

Change to JSON.Net helped.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error, it was caused by a method that was calling itself after some refactoring, so thank you test.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by installing the [Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK).

1. Open the **Tools** tab
2. Choose the **NuGet Package Manager** sub-menu
3. Click on the **Manage NuGet packages for solution** menuitem
4. Install the **Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk**